# Clicking on links in a fixed menu, covering the whole screen does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to create a menu that is shown for mobile devices. The goal is to click on a "menu" button to toggle the menu. The menu should cover the entire screen and you should be able to navigate around the app through its links and buttons (the NuxtLink-tags).

Im successful in showing the menu and its links, however when i click them, they dont take me to their right place, the menu simply closes.

Heres the code.

```
// HTML
<template>
<!-- Small screen view  -->
    <div class="mobile-view">
      <NuxtLink class="navbar-img" tag="img" src="" alt="HästBild" to="/">
      </NuxtLink>
      <button class="btn-menu">Meny</button>
      <!-- This is opened when pressing the menu button -->
      <div class="mobile-menu">
        <div class="top-section">
          <NuxtLink class="navbar-img" tag="img" src="" alt="HästBild" to="/">
          </NuxtLink>
          <a class="close-icon">
            <img src="@/assets/close-icon.png" alt="Closing symbol" />
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          <div v-for="header in listHeaders" :key="header.name">
            <NuxtLink :to="header.page" class="list-item">{{
              header.name
            }}</NuxtLink>
          </div>

          <div class="content-buttons">
            <NuxtLink to="/createaccount" class="btn text--white"
              >Skapa konto</NuxtLink
            >
            <NuxtLink to="/#" class="btn white text--black">Logga in</NuxtLink>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
// CSS
<style>
.btn-menu:focus + .mobile-menu {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  .mobile-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99 !important;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #333361;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .close-icon:focus-within img + .mobile-menu {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .content {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
</style>
```

```
// JS
<script>
export default {
  name: "NavBar",
  data: () => {
    return {
      listHeaders: [
        { name: "page 1", page: "#" },
        { name: "page 2", page: "#" },
        { name: "page 3", page: "#" },
        { name: "page 4", page: "FAQ" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

Comment: Even if you click on the last one ?

Comment: Correct, the menu simply shuts down without registering any click or navigates me to the pressed link

Comment: I also noticed that if i set the visibility: visible;
the links work just fine, but when i keep it like before the visibility changes to hidden before the click is registered or something...

Comment: You could use a data property to trigger the visiblility instead of using the :focus pseudo element

Comment: Haha, I did not even think of that. But yes, that works and I am going with that solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charles Lavalard wrote in the comments:

"You could use a data property to trigger the visiblility instead of using the :focus pseudo element"

For this project this is actually a smooth solution.

Code:

```
<div @click="mobileView = true"></div>

<div v-if="mobileView>
...
</div>
```